# How to add string to column values but ignore empty fields

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have the following code below to select a column from my table and add `'abcd'` string to all the values in my column. However, how would I go about ignoring the empty values so rows 10-14 would be empty and while rows 1-9 would remain the same?

```
SELECT 

vendor + 'abcd'AS [vendor_key]

FROM [table]
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a **`CASE`** expression.

**Query**

```
select case when len(ltrim(rtrim([vendor]))) > 0 then [vendor] + 'abcd'
            else [vendor] end as [vendor_key]
from [your_table_name];
```

Comment: Thanks for the response however, I am getting the same values as the original column without the added string.

Answer (score 1):

Presumably, `vendor` is an empty string.  Just convert it to `NULL` in this case:

```
SELECT NULLIF(vendor, '') + 'abcd' AS vendor_key
FROM [table]
```

Note that `+` returns `NULL` if any of the arguments are `NULL`.  This contrasts with `CONCAT()` which ignores `NULL` values.

You don't seem to have any spaces in the results, so you don't seem to have spaces in the original data -- and `trim()` does not seem necessary.